# Is it safe to manage security rules in flask views/functions instead of in firebase when using python flask with firebase storage?

Tags: python, firebase, flask, firebase-storage

I'm pretty new to web development and I'm currently building a python flask web app and using:

- a postgres database on heroku
- flask-login for user authentication instead of firebase authentication
- firebase storage to store images uploaded by users

As a user, I should:

- be able to read all images uploaded by all users
- only be able to edit or delete images that I've uploaded

My questions:
Is it safe to manage security rules through my python flask views/functions (i.e. instead of via the rules section in firebase) and simply set the storage 'allow read/write' security rules in firebase to 'if true'?

If I set the firebase storage read/write security rules to 'if true', is it possible for a user/bad actor (i.e. that is not on my web app) to use CRUD operations on my firebase storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can write code that is equally secure as the security rules that you can write, then it is possible to secure file access purely through code, just as it is possible to secure file access purely through security rules.

But in that case you must set your security rules to `if false` (fully closed) instead of `if true` (fully open) as the latter allows anyone to do whatever they want to the files through the API, while you instead want all access to go through you code.

If the rules are set to fully closed, only a user from a trusted environment will have access to the files, while all access through the Firebase client-side SDK will be blocked.

One thing to consider is not using Firebase for Storage in such a scenario, and instead using only the Cloud Storage SDKs. If you create a regular bucket in Cloud Storage (instead of though the Firebase console), and don't associate it with Firebase, the Firebase SDKs won't be able to access the files in that bucket, and all access will have to go through server-side APIs that you provide.